# Android Hello World

Tags: android

I am using android.com tutorial to learn android using eclipse. I have just started 1st program. It says `Open the Android folder, select Android Project and click Next. But there is no new`Android Project` option in android folder, rather it has three options for a new project. 
1) android application project
2) android sample project
3) android test project

which is one I should choose for creating an Android project for that tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the android application project.

Comment: FYI: If you do not see "Android Application Project" under File > New, then select "Project..." open the Android folder, and select Android Application Project. From then on it should show up in the File > New list.